Which angular version should be used for node version 20.15.1
I upgraded node version 14 to version 20.15.1 and upgraded angular-cli to version 17.3.8 but I am facing peer depedencies version mismatch error.How can I handle it. I did npm i and updated all package version in package.json and deleted package-lock.json.


When I went through this upgrade hell I ended up having to look at the documentation for every package involved, work out myself the dependencies, and then manually upgrade packages, 1 minor version at a time, installing and building after change. It was slow, painful and frustrating. But eventually I got there.

Clear npm cache:
Run the following command to clear the npm cache:
npm cache clean --force

Remove node_modules directory:
Delete the node_modules directory to ensure a clean slate
rm -rf node_modules

Reinstall dependencies:
Reinstall all dependencies by running:
npm install

Use npm ls to identify peer dependency issues:
Run the following command to list all installed packages and identify any peer dependency issues:
npm ls

Resolve peer dependency issues:
Manually: Review the output of npm ls and manually update the dependencies in your package.json file to match the required versions.
Using
npm install --force or --legacy-peer-deps

Use npx npm-check-updates:
Install npm-check-updates globally if you haven't already:
 npm install -g npm-check-updates

run the following command to update your package.json
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm install

Check Angular CLI specific dependencies:
ng update


Is this another ChatGPT answer?

Thanks I did manually changing the peer dependencies version in package.json file and did npm i. It worked.

@DaleK Already I have faced this issue and hence I have shared these steps
